# Unable to find meaning to the fields in the findOneAndUpdate query for mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can someone help me understand the meaning of the parameters in the query below:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate([conditions], [update], [options], [callback])
```

I understand the `[update]`, `[options]` and `[callback]` part but `[conditions]` is not very clear for me. It's a common set of parameters in most queries but since I am new to Node and MongoDB, putting things into perspective is not very natural to me yet.

I couldn't find much help on the the official site as well.
Might be a trivial question but it will go a long way in understanding the query structure for Mongoose.

Comment: Condition - what are you going to modify, update - how are you going to modify it, callback what will happened after this modification will happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the method `findOneAndUpdate()` implies that with it, you can find a single document of a model in the database, and update that document.

But you obviously need to specify *which* document in the database you want to update. That's what `[conditions]` is used for: it tells Mongoose "*find me a document matching these conditions, and update the first document you can find*". (the '*first document*' part is useful to know, because the conditions might match multiple documents and `findOne*` will only ever change one document).

So the `[conditions]` are the query that Mongoose uses to find matching documents (more on queries [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)).

If you want to change the `name` of a document where the `email` field has a certain value, it'd look something like this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
  email : 'foo@example.com'
}, {
  name  : 'Foo Bar'
}, ...);
```

Comment: I used the update() which essentially does the same thing. How is the findOneAndUpdate different to it?

Comment: @Zooter depends on which `update()` you used: [`Model.update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) or [`Document.update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update)

Comment: I am using the Model.update, which is working the same way was findOneAndUpdate. The difference is the options parameter I guess. That separates the two.

Comment: @Zooter `Model.update` can match/change multiple documents, depending on the query that you use. `findOneAndUpdate` will only match/change one document.